# ideas on flexible function to describe this data?

Tags: functions

I am trying to think of as simple as possible of a function that could to do a decent job at fitting the curves in the figure below. I have tried various sigmoid functions (e.g., logistic), a simple linear spline, and a quadratic spline but none seem to do a great job. More than two parameters may be a bit much (as I will have to fit these from data) but I am open to any suggestions. 
[image]

Comment: Your functions $f(x,\dots)$ seem to decrease from $1$ to $0$ monotonically. If you use $1-f(x,\dots)$ you are in the setting of cumulative distribution functions from statistics, where there is an arsenal of similar-shaped curves e.g.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution or 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Answer (score 1):

something like

$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   {{\left( 1-\frac{x}{a} \right)}^{b}} & if{{\left( 1-\frac{x}{a} \right)}^{b}}>g(x)  \\
   g(x) & otherwise  \\
\end{matrix} \right.
$

Here g(x) is your fixed black curve ($x^{-1}$ or some multiple?), b is a number less than 1 and a ranges between 10 and 100. Ish.